# jsp page not loading if another user is loading page

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have a jsp page that is performing a select and then needs to display a lot of data. It can take a minute or so to load. The issue I am having is that if another user tries to access said page, they just get a spinning browser until the first user's page has completed. I was able to duplicate this with the following test page

The page is:

```
<%@ page isThreadSafe="false" import="java.util.*" errorPage="error2.jsp" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<% 
    for (int i = 1;i <= 10000; i++) { %>
          line <%=i%>&nbsp;<%=new Date()%><br>
         <% for (int j = 1;j <= 900000; j++) {
         }
    }
%>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to this page on two browsers at the same time, both start to spin , one will start to display the "line 1.... " data the other will continue to spin until the first one displays "line 10000..." and then the second browser will start to display.

The first and last lines of display in the first browser are:

line 1 Wed Jan 16 15:35:25 EST 2019
line 10000 Wed Jan 16 15:35:39 EST 2019

and the first and last lines of display in the second browser are:

line 1 Wed Jan 16 15:35:39 EST 2019
line 10000 Wed Jan 16 15:35:53 EST 2019

I have been able to duplicate this in JBoss 7 and in Wildfly 9. Both in standalone mode.

Is there some setting in standalone.xml that I need to set  so that two JBoss/Wildfly will produce two or more instances of the same page at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is the "isThreadSafe" page directive attribute. When I change it from false to true, the pages are displayed in multiple browsers concurrently.